# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы поле 2 принимала такое же значений, как и поле 1 при операции INSERT INTO в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть несколько полей, хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы при вставке новой строке поле 2 принимала такое же значение как поле 1.
Поле 1 - первичный ключ с авто-крементом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Один вопрос: зачем?

Comment: модель базы данных такая

Comment: А можно подробнее? В целом-то зачем 2-ому полю копировать значение 1-го? Почему не использовать 1-ое всегда?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Значение автоинкремента недоступно до завершения процесса вставки, т.е. не может быть получено в триггерах/вычисляемых полях/значениях по умолчанию. Только решение в два запроса, возможно, в формате хранимой процедуры.

Comment: Если очень хочется, то можно. Путем создания отдельной таблицы генератора. Но зачем?

Comment: Вот модель БД на картинке, я предполагал, что нужно сделать несколько полей id и shops_pk и связать их

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Ну тогда это будет по факту не автоинкремент в **этой** таблице. Это не говоря о проблемах, если пройдёт вставка в обход.

Comment: @Akina а если вставка через транзакцию и триггер после коммита?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov пойду погуглю, что это )

Comment: @Akina В этой - нет. А обхода никакого не будет, если сделать на `BEFORE INSERT` триггере

Comment: @teran В MySQL? Если вставка выполняется в транзакции, то триггер будет выполнен в рамках транзакции. Вставить коммит между запросом и вызванным его выполнением триггером невозможно даже теоретически.

Comment: @teran из триггера нельзя модифицировать ту же таблицу, к которой привязан триггер. Все что можно - это модифицировать поля конкретной записи в `BEFORE' триггере

Comment: думал, что есть after commit триггеры, а таких нет.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы, вопрос закрыт